# I am uploading images in live web server, the server responds to error,while image are uploading successfully on local server in visual studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have developed a website in Asp.net mvc and store data in sql server database.
I am uploading images,inside project folder directory,images uploaded successfully
on local server in database.

But the problem is that live server gives an error while i upload images,I have purchased the shared server, where I have deployed my website.

The below code are using to save image,it is working properly on local server,
but it is giving an error on live server.

```
    public string SaveImagingData(string fileName, HttpPostedFileBase image)
    {

        // your configuration here...
        string miliSec = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
        string imageName = null;
        string physicalPath = "~/Content/images/";

        if (image != null && image.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            imageName = Regex.Replace(fileName, @"\s", "_") + "_" + miliSec + Path.GetExtension(Path.GetFileName(image.FileName));
            string path = Server.MapPath(physicalPath + imageName);

            // save image in folder
            image.SaveAs(path);

        }
        return imageName;
    }
```

Comment: What is the exact error statement / stack trace that you receive while uploading the images?

Comment: Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off"

Comment: This is the error I received

Comment: This error message isn't very helpful as all it says is that detailed error messages are disabled in your web.config. Which of course, should be the case with live production servers.

Comment: You should use `try .. catch` to catch the exception and return the exception message instead of impageName in case of exception. You should also use some logging framework such as log4net to log the messages at various places in code so that you can analyze the log files to understand what is happening in your code in live environment.

Comment: Check the uploading folders are available in the production environment, And If you are already using some logging mechanism then apply some logs and catch the exception since you are using Custom Error Page.

Comment: Access to the path 'C:\Inetpub\vhosts\arisetech.net\bftraders.com\Content\images\3-png_636632045220343152.png' is denied.

Comment: I received the above error.When i upload the image.how i give the path to store the image.